# Difference between command handlers and aggregate methods in functional DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

Following a functional programming paradigm, I have a CQRS architecture with event sourcing as the main persistence mechanism.

Currently my aggregates consist of

- a set of command handlers (behavior)
- a reducer to fold events to the current aggregate state (data)

A command handler does

1. fetch the event stream for a given aggregateId
2. folds the current aggregate state
3. applies some business logic based on the current state
4. persist any events created in step 3

Example of a command handler

```
type CommandHandler = (
  state: AggregateState,
  command: Command
) => E.Either<Err.Err, DomainEvent[] | void>;
```

Basically steps 1, 2 and 4 are abstracted away in a generic function:

```
// pseudo-code
const wrapCommandHanler = (handler: CommandHandler) => {
  return wrapped = (command: Command) => {
    const events = fetchEvents();
    const state = applyReducer(events);
    const newEvents = handler(state, command);
    persistEvents(newEvents);
  }
}
```

So my command handlers are quite lean and focused and only contain the business logic.

I read about DDD, but the given examples were following a OOP paradigm. In these examples the command handler would call an aggregate method where the aggregate is a class that contains state and domain logic.

But in my case the aggregate state and behavior is separated and my command handlers ARE the aggregate behavior. So my command handlers contain the domain logic.

My question(s):
Is this approach "correct" / valid DDD or am I shooting myself in the foot with this? If not, what is the main purpose of separating an aggregate function and a command handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing pure functional DDD, the commands (I'm deliberately not using "object") correspond to the methods of an aggregate (if using types, you can say that the type corresponds to the interface and each instance to an invocation; the ultimate handler function corresponds to the body of the method).

Technically, if event sourcing, it's the *pas de deux* of the command and event handler which define the aggregate, though the command handler probably carries more of the load.

These two definitions of an aggregate in Scala are effectively the same thing.  For the OO-style, I'm using a more "durable state" approach and the FP-style is event-sourced (OO-style event-sourced (aggregate methods return a `Seq[Event]` and you have some means of defining event handlers) and FP-style durable-state (no `EventHandler` and the command handler returns a `State`) are both possible, but IME feel unnatural).  Both are equivalently unit-testable (event-sourced arguably moreso, especially for property-based testing):

```scala
// Note that Map here is an immutable Map (i.e. a value object)
// Domain has been simplified: assume that Item includes price and there are no discounts etc.

// OO and "durable state"-style persistence... application basically loads a cart from persistence, maps external commands into method calls, saves cart
class ShoppingCart(val itemCounts: Map[Item, Int], val checkedOut: Boolean = false) {
  def addItem(item: Item, qty: Int): Unit =
    // Collapsing the failed validations into a single do-nothing case
    if (!checkedOut && qty > 0) {
      itemCounts.get(item) match {
        case Some(count) =>
          itemCounts = itemCounts.updated(item, count + qty)

        case None =>
          itemCounts = itemCounts + (item -> qty)
      }
    }

  def adjustQtyOfItem(item: Item, newQty: Int): Unit =
    if (!checkedOut && itemCounts.contains(item)) {
      newQty match {
        case neg if neg < 0 =>
          // do nothing
          ()

        case pos if pos > 0 =>
          itemCounts = itemCounts.updated(item, newQty)

        case 0 =>
          itemCounts = itemCounts - item
      }
    }

  def removeAllOfItem(item: Item): Unit =
    adjustQtyOfItem(item, 0)

  def checkOut(): Unit =
    if (!checkedOut) {
      checkedOut = true
    }
}

// FP and event-sourced persistence
object ShoppingCart {
  case class State(itemCounts: Map[Item, Int], checkedOut: Boolean)

  sealed trait Command
  case class AddItem(item: Item, qty: Int) extends Command
  case class AdjustQtyOfItem(item: Item, newQty: Int) extends Command
  case object CheckOut extends Command

  val RemoveAllOfItem: Item => Command = AdjustQtyOfItem(_, 0)

  sealed trait Event
  case class ItemsAdded(item: Item, qty: Int) extends Event
  case class ItemsRemoved(item: Item, qtyRemoved: Int) extends Event
  case class AllOfItemRemoved(item: Item) extends Event
  case object CheckedOut extends Event

  val CommandHandler: (State, Command) => Seq[Event] = handleCommand(_, _)
  val EventHandler: (State, Event) => State = handleEvent(_, _)
  val InitialState = State(Map.empty, false)

  private def handleCommand(state: State, cmd: Command): Seq[Event] =
    if (!state.checkedOut) {
      cmd match {
        case AddItem(item, qty) if qty > 0 => Seq(ItemAdded(item, qty))
        case AdjustQtyOfItem(item, newQty) if state.itemCounts.contains(item)  && newQty >= 0 =>
          val currentQty = state.itemCounts(item)

          if (newQty > currentQty) {
            handleCommand(state, AddItem(item, newQty - currentQty))
          } else if (newQty == 0) {
            Seq(AllOfItemRemoved(item))
          } else {
            Seq(ItemsRemoved(item, currentQty - newQty))
          }

        case CheckOut => Seq(CheckedOut)
        case _ => Seq.empty
      }
    } else Seq.empty

  private def handleEvent(state: State, evt: Event): State =
    evt match {
      case ItemsAdded(item, qty) =>
        state.get(item)
          .map { prevQty =>
            state.copy(itemCounts = state.itemCounts.updated(item, prevQty + qty))
          }
          .getOrElse {
            state.copy(itemCounts = state.itemCounts + (item, qty))
          }

      case ItemsRemoved(item, qtyRemoved) =>
        state.get(item)
          .map { prevQty =>
            state.copy(itemCounts = state.itemCounts.updated(item, prevQty - qtyRemoved))
          }
          .getOrElse(state)

      case AllOfItemRemoved(item) =>
        state.copy(itemCounts = state.itemCounts - item)

      case CheckedOut =>
        state.copy(checkedOut = true)
    }
}
```

Part of the confusion probably stems from "command handler" having a specific meaning in the application layer (where it's something from outside) and a slightly different meaning in the context of an event-sourced aggregate (the application layer command handler in an event-sourced application is basically just an anti-corruption layer translating external commands into commands against the aggregate (for instance the commands against the aggregate probably shouldn't contain an ID for the aggregate: the aggregate knows its ID)).

Answer (score 4):

You'll probably want to review [Jérémie Chassaing](https://thinkbeforecoding.com/)'s recent work on [Decider](https://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2021/12/17/functional-event-sourcing-decider)

> My question(s): Is this approach "correct" / valid DDD or am I shooting myself in the foot with this?

It's fine - there's no particular reason that you need your functional design to align with "Java best practices" circa 2003.

> If not, what is the main purpose of separating an aggregate function and a command handler?

Primarily to create a clear boundary between the abstractions of the problem domain (ex: "Cargo Shipping") and the "plumbing" - the application logic that knows about I/O, messaging, databases and transactions, HTTP, and so on.

Among other things, that means you can take the aggregate "module" (so to speak) and move it to other contexts, without disturbing the relationships of the different domain functions.

That said, there's nothing magic going on - you could refactor your "functional" design and create a slightly different design the gives you similar benefits to what you get from "aggregates".

Comment: Thank you for the very interesting read. This describes exactly what I was doing (while naming things different).

Answer (score -3):

> Is this approach "correct" / valid DDD or am I shooting myself in the foot with this?

DDD is based on two principles :

- You should model your business logic (BL) using OOP in a "domain layer"
- The domain layer contains the BL, the whole BL and nothing but the BL

By putting your business logic in your reducers you have failed the DDD principles and have achieved an [anemic domain model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model). Your domain is indeed so anemic that it is even not modeled using OOP. This is important because by doing so, you violate the single responsibility principle (SRP) by having your reducers having two responsibilities : translating a series of event into state *and* validating business rules.

> If not, what is the main purpose of separating an aggregate function and a command handler?

With the query handlers, command handlers implement parts of the interface specification, and lies in the application layer. It receive information from the clients (commands) and does some low level validation (for instance, reject malformed messages or unauthenticated requests). The command handler then calls other layers for them to do their job: the infrastructure layer for event store access, reducers for event to aggregates translation, and the domain layer for business rules validation and integrity. The code in these handlers is application specific as another application in the same domain will inherently have different interface specification and different commands to handle.

Aggregates are responsible for business logic and business rules. It is an abstraction of the actual concepts you are trying to manipulate. Good domain modeling try to be as application ignorant as possible, in order to increase reusability. A domain model could be used for multiple applications that does similar business. Whether you implement a piece of software used by pharmacists when delivering medications, or another one used by medicine doctors to prescribe them, you can use the same domain layer modeling drug interactions. Using OOP in your domain layer allows to model very complex business logic using very simple code. By putting the business logic in a separate layer, you can have a small team of developers working closely with business experts of the matter, to model all the business logic, constraints and processes, relevant to a set of applications. You can even unit test your domain.

Please note that your approach is perfectly acceptable, and can be very efficient. Doing DDD for the purpose of doing DDD is not a good practice. Doing good DDD modeling is not an easy task and should be considered as a mean of reducing complexity of large domain models.

Comment: DDD does not in any way, shape, or form imply OOP.

Comment: In fact, DDD done properly tends to be closer to FP than traditional OOP and a great many of the tactical patterns in the Blue Book are basically techniques for emulating FP in an OO language.